# How to detect Click on the window's title bar?

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

Is there any way to detect click on the window's title bar or on the window's frame using pygt5 in Python?

Comment: No - the title-bar and frame are normally provided by the window manager, so you will have to write your own implementation.

Comment: Bad news. Thank you ekhumoro